# Creating a basic function

Tags: python, function, networking, ssh, paramiko

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

r1 = {'ip': '10.1.1.1', 'device_type': 'juniper', 'username': 'test', 'password': 'test1'}

r2 = {'ip': '10.1.1.2', 'device_type': 'juniper', 'username': 'test', 'password': 'test1'}

def connect(**cred):
    ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(**cred)

connect(r1)
```

This is some basic function i have been playing around with, but i seem to be struggling on the basics. I am using Netmiko, and i want to be able to list devices and create a function so that i can import it into other scripts.

I'd just like to to create a function connects to devices, but it will connect to whatever device i mention in the function, however this doesnt seem to be working - where am i going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's not working? You don't do anything other than create the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing this:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

r1 = {'ip': '10.1.1.1', 'device_type': 'juniper', 'username': 'test', 'password': 'test1'}

r2 = {'ip': '10.1.1.2', 'device_type': 'juniper', 'username': 'test', 'password': 'test1'}
```

If you say ConnectHandler class takes (*args, **kwargs) then your function should look like:

```
def connect(*args, **cred):
    ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(*args, **cred)

connect(**r1)
```

`*args` are added optionally if sometime you'll want to add them.
The thing is you are using `**cred` as `kwargs` signature but you don't pass keyword args to function, passing positional arguments instead.

Comment: connect(cred = r1)

tried this and got this and error, shown below:

'code'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mohammedd/code/scripts2.0/first_function.py", line 13, in <module>
    connect(cred = r1)
  File "/Users/mohammedd/code/scripts2.0/first_function.py", line 11, in connect
    ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(**cred)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 131, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)'code'